# Multi-tenant app: Mongodb Sharding One database for all tenant VS One database for each tenant

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multi-tenant, sharding

I am building a Multi-tenant SaaS app, where I have many customers (can span from hundreds to thousands). Each of these customers have customers of their own, who can make accounts and interact on our app. 
I am using Node for my server and MongoDB for the Database.

Currently, my approach to storing my tenants' data is placing all their data in **one database** and to use **Mongodb Sharding** to partition all my tenant's data and scale up when I need it in the future. MongoDB sharding seems to me like a great way to partition and manage my data.

However, **there are some people who recommend that I should have one database for each tenant**. They say it is better, as it is easier to "migrate/manage/scale" and "more secure". I would like to get a second opinion on this.

Giving each tenant a database increases the complexity of my app, so I would like to know if its really necessary.

I would be grateful for any insights. Thank you in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

These are my opinions and would love to discuss.

There are several well-known ways to store tenant based data. I think it depends on your solution, budget, size of the team and where you want to put the complexity.

- **Database system instance per tenant**: We generally use this method for `on-premise` solutions. Tenants use and manage their own database instance on their own server/cloud.
- **Database per tenant**: This is the most secure way to isolate tenants' data from each others for a cloud solution. But needs extra efforts for maintenance and management (backing-up, development changes, reindexing, etc). Furthermore, the application should be able to handle / pool the connection for per database.
- **Schema per tenant** (in MongoDb world this will not be possible since it does not have schema)
- **Table/collection per tenant**:
- **Row / document per tenant**: Provides weak isolation. And have to be optimized well for each kind of queries. However, easiest way to maintain.

**Considering a solution that is maintained by a very small team (2 or 3 people):** I would use `document-based isolation (with a field tenantId)` and have several `sharded clusters` to scale the tenant data by using tenants' names' initials as sharding key.

- cluster#01: Tenants with the names starts with A-H
- cluster#02: Tenants with the names starts with H-S
- ...

**Considering a cloud solution that is used by thousands of customers worldwide and maintained by a large team**:
Probably I will go with having `sharded clusters` (in different country locations), and spread the tenants into the respective sharded cluster by tenant's location and have `database per tenant`.

**Considering an enterprise solution:** I prefer to offer `on-premise` to customers.

**Additionally to all above**: I can consider to use slave `replica sets` to execute the read operations rather than using the primary instance.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "document-based isolation (with a field tenantId)", do you mean all tenant documents placed in one database? Is this a common method?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I meant one database collection includes data from multiple tenants. But please be noticed, I did not say from all tenants. Above, I scaled them into several sharded databases. I just now found a link from Microsoft that tells about multi-tenant storage patterns. Hope this helps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/saas-tenancy-app-design-patterns